# How to build a web service rest in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest

I'm building a simple web service with visual basic. This web services should to get in input a JSON and return a value.
The method of this web service is POST.

This is the code:

```
    <WebMethod()>
        Public Function MB_InsertBeetrader(ByVal inputData As AMAServerInputData) As AMAServerOutputData
            Dim returnData As New AMAServerOutputData()

            Try


            Catch ex As Exception
                returnData.Messages.AddExceptionMessage(ex)
            End Try

            Return returnData
        End Function
    End Class

Public Class AMAServerInputData
    Inherits Base_ServerInputData
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
End Class
```

If I try to call this method from my PostMan client I have an error.
This is my call:

```
{ "Username": 656, 
"Password": "128"
}
```

This is the error:

> {
>     "Message": "Chiamata a servizio Web non valida. Valore mancante per il parametro 'inputData'.",
>     "StackTrace": "   in System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
>     "

Answer (score 1):

It appears the web service is not recognizing the data you are passing in for the request. This could be due to variables not being set that belong to your Base_ServerInputData object you are inheriting from.

A few options to consider:

1. Remove the inheritance on your object
2. Include the appropriate variables in your post request
3. Change the web method signature to require the variables individually since you only have two of them in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give me an example?

Comment: @bircastri An example of what?